# How to check popup.html page when action occurs within content.js (Chrome Extension)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension needs to check if a checkbox is checked on the popup.html while on the page that the extension is active.

**content.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  time = setInterval(function () {
    if(true){
      //check if checkbox is checked??
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

**popup.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<input type="checkbox" name="thingToDo" value="isChecked"> Do thing<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to kind of scrape the popup.html from content.js? Or will I need a background.js and some sort of message sending back and forth?

Comment: Since your injecting the script into the webpage, avoid using a timer. Just attach a handler directly onto the checkbox. `$('checkbox[name="thingToDo"]').change(...)`

Comment: You can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) API.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a direct communication between `popup.html` and `content.js`, but the usual way is to use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) API.

Set the `checked` status via `popup.html` and listen for storage changes in `content.js`.

So whenever or from whereever the storage value gets changed, you will get in the `content.js`

It's the easy way and clean way too.